# Internet browser for 2003 laptop

Tags: laptop, browser, ubuntu-14.04

I own a **2003 laptop** which is **Acer Travelmate 240**. I installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with XFCE4**.

It's got *Pentium 4 2,8 Ghz single core CPU , 1GB of RAM and Intel Graphics 82855*.

Everything works just fine, except I can't find suitable browser for it.
I've tried Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Konqueror - **nope**. They use 100% of my CPU and **bam**, laptop overheats.

**Midori** is quite usable, but it doesn't support many websites, eg. codeacademy.

Is there any better browser which would run smooth on this laptop or should I throw it out of the window?

**EDIT**:

To clear everything up - Ubuntu is fine on this laptop. When it comes to memory usage it uses only 150 MB after logon.
It's just the browser which hogs on  my CPU - it also happened on Debian btw.

Comment: It sounds like you should use an OS with a smaller footprint then Ubuntu.  1GB is barely enough memory for Ubuntu itself.

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound, for example Puppy or one of its derivatives would scream on this hardware. A much less resource intensive distro would help a lot.

Comment: Its really simple.  Today's websites are not designed for computers with less then 512 MB of available memory.  I have tabs on my machine that take up 80 MB by themselves, once I open a couple dozen tabs, and I can easily use 1 GB. In reality when I load my typical saved session of Chrome, Firefox, or Edge they all consume between 2-3 GB.  Of course I also open hundreds of tabs in those browsers.  [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm)

Comment: Puppy Linux will only use around 100 MB of memory.  This will allow you to use a modern browser, but you will still be limited, to a couple tabs at most and will most definitely not be able to watch YouTube on it.  [Firefox, Opera, and Chrome](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) are all supported on it

Comment: You guys dramatize the situation. A few years ago a Pentium 4 and 1GB of RAM was top of the line. Those browsers should all work without problems. If the PC overheats, there must be a different problem - maybe too much dust.

Comment: @whs Pent 4 were released 15 years ago.  How do I know this because my PC in 2001 had a Pent 4 CPU.  While I agree the overheating problem is an entirely separate problem that wasn't the authors question. Besides  1GB wasn't enough in 2007 which is when Windows 7 was released.

Comment: I have an old XP-era desktop that had 1 GB RAM.  That was adequate to run Mint Mate and Firefox or Chrome.  I couldn't have more than a few tabs open in Firefox before it slowed way down, but it worked fine.  With 1GB, you can do a little better than Puppy in terms of a more full-featured featherweight OS.  Check out [Porteus](http://www.porteus.org/).  It's RAM resident with a choice of modern desktops (a bit stripped down), and current browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should clean whole laptop, use new thermal paste and try it again, if it wont help, try live edition of lubuntu, puppy or so...

Comment: To add to that. The problem is not the OS or the lack of memory. That merely might make it very slow (and paging). It should never overheat though. Worst case it should throttle the CPU. If it overheats then the cooling is failing. Clean dust. If needed re-apply thermal paste.

Comment: Yeah, the CPU may throtle because of overheating because of failing / messsy (dust, vecy old thermal paste) cooling...